# For each date in range, get records with date in range

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let’s say I have a table `Orders` and each order has a `CreatedDate` and a `DeliveredDate` column.

How can I select for each date in a range a count that includes all records where the date is between `CreatedDate` and `DeliveredDate`? Let's say getting results for the range 2021-10-04 to 2021-10-09

If the `Orders` table looks like this

```
ID       CreatedOn      DeliveredOn       
1        2021-10-04     2021-10-04      
2        2021-10-06     2021-10-07      
3        2021-10-06     2021-10-08 
4        2021-10-07     2021-10-08      
5        2021-10-08     2021-10-09
```

The result should look like this

```
Date            ActiveCount
2021-10-04      1
2021-10-05      0
2021-10-06      2
2021-10-07      3
2021-10-08      3
2021-10-09      1
```

So order 1 only applies towards the count of 2021-10-04 but order 3 applies towards the count of 2021-10-06, 2021-10-07, and 2021-10-08 because that is the day it is delivered on.

I’m not great with SQL and I am having trouble wrapping my head around how to do this. If someone could point me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Where is the date range in your results coming from?  Do you have a dates table, or are you getting it from user input or stored procedure parameters?  Defined in another table that you're joining on?  Hardcoded in the query?

Comment: @squillman This is for a stored procedure and the date range will be coming from the parameters. Right now I have a procedure that joins on a dates table to make sure I get a count for the dates that don't have any records associated with them. The procedure I have now groups by one date so that each record counts towards one day in the range. I need each record to potentially count towards more than one day depending on the two dates in the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you will generate the dates table in your procedure based off of the input parameter values, you just need a `LEFT JOIN` and a `COUNT` with `GROUP BY`:

```
DECLARE @Dates TABLE ([Date] DATE);
DECLARE @Orders TABLE (ID INT, CreatedOn DATE, DeliveredOn DATE);

INSERT @Dates ([Date])
VALUES ('2021-10-04'),('2021-10-05'),('2021-10-06'),
       ('2021-10-07'),('2021-10-08'),('2021-10-09');

INSERT @Orders (ID, CreatedOn, DeliveredOn)
VALUES (1, '2021-10-04', '2021-10-04'),
       (2, '2021-10-06', '2021-10-07'),
       (3, '2021-10-06', '2021-10-08'),
       (4, '2021-10-07', '2021-10-08'),
       (5, '2021-10-08', '2021-10-09');

SELECT d.[Date], COUNT(ID) AS ActiveCount
FROM @Dates d
LEFT JOIN @Orders o ON o.CreatedOn <= d.[Date] AND o.DeliveredOn >= d.[Date]
GROUP BY d.[Date];
```

Order of the tables is important here.  You want to see all of the dates in the range so you start with that table.  The `LEFT JOIN` will return all of the records from that table and bring in records from the Orders table where the JOIN condition matches.  You'll get a separate record for each match so use `COUNT` with `GROUP BY` to get the total count by day.

Comment: Thank you. This a exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a table containing all the dates, something along the lines of this should work:

```
SELECT d.[date] as [Date], COUNT(*) as ActiveCount
FROM dates d
WHERE d.[date] >= @startDate AND d.[date] <= @endDate
LEFT JOIN orders o ON o.CreatedDate <= d.[date] and o.DeliveredDate >= d.[date]
GROUP BY d.[date]
ORDER BY [Date]
```